# Find stacked div class with Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: parsing, class, html, domparser

I am using [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) and there is a section in the html page with the following source:

```
<div class="box-content padding-top-1 padding-bottom-1 font-size-3">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="link1">linkdescription 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="link2">linkdescription 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How can I now get the list of links with using the stacked class identifier?

Here's what I've currently tried:

- `List item $html->find('.box-content padding-top-1 padding-bottom-1 font-size-3'));`

  - returns empty
- `List item $html->find('.box-content'));`

  - returns other page elements in a box
- `List item $html->find('.box-content+padding-top-1+padding-bottom-1+font-size-3'));`

  - never mind :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can try this:

```
List item $html->find('div[class=box-content padding-top-1 padding-bottom-1 font-size-3]');
```

Answer (score 1):

For targeting an element with multiple classes, use dot (`.`) as the separator between classes. Spaces indicate a parent -> child relationship.

So, in your example, you would need:

```
List item $html->find('.box-content.padding-top-1.padding-bottom-1.font-size-3'));
```