# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser : Select two classes

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

My problem is very simple .
Let's say I have multiple 'a' :

```
    <td class="autoindex_td">

        <a class="autoindex_a snap_shots" href="http://example.com.html">
            <img height="16" width="16" src="http://exmple.com/download/index_icons/winxp/sound.png" alt="[mp3]"></img>
            <strong>

                05 - example.mp3

            </strong>
        </a>
   </td>
```

I just want to find 'strong' which has two classes . Here what I tried :

```
foreach ($html->find('a[class=autoindex_a , class=snap_shots]') as $link) {
    if(isset($link)){
   foreach($link->find('strong') as $tag)
       {
             $name = $tag->plaintext ;
             $hiren[] = $name ;
       }
     }
   }
```

But I get `null` .So how do I select two class at the same time ?

Comment: Next time, please make a search for similar questions before posting => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387958/find-stacked-div-class-with-simple-html-dom-parser

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just found a way :

```
 foreach ($html->find('a[class=autoindex_a snap_shots]') as $link) {
    if(isset($link)){
   foreach($link->find('strong') as $tag)
       {
             $name = $tag->plaintext ;
             $hiren[] = $name ;
       }
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) Class ?

```
<?php

$html=' <td class="autoindex_td">

        <a class="autoindex_a snap_shots" href="http://example.com.html">
            <img height="16" width="16" src="http://exmple.com/download/index_icons/winxp/sound.png" alt="[mp3]"></img>
            <strong>

                05 - example.mp3

            </strong>
        </a>
   </td>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $tag) {
    if ($tag->getAttribute('class') === 'autoindex_a snap_shots') {
        foreach($tag->getElementsByTagName('strong') as $strongTag)
        {
        echo $strongTag->nodeValue; //"prints"  05 - example.mp3
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks . But I didnt choose this library , my project manager did !

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate the attribute finders as:

```
$html->find("a[class='autoindex_a'][class='snap_shots']")
```

or, separate the classes with a dot `.` separator:

```
$html->find('a.autoindex_a.snap_shots')
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a method to select elements that fits all those criteria, at once. It returns an array of the elements that fit in all the criteria, or an array of zero elements.
It accepts either an array of elements or a single element.
The criteria needs to be delimited by commas, and it will returned elements that fit in all those criteria.
Example usage

```
$dom = new simple_html_dom();
$dom->load($Email);
//This would select elements with only those selected criteria
//Then what is returned is an array, and then we select further elements that
//are em
$selection = GetSelectionMultiple($dom, "font, .ff2, .fs16, .fc1, .fwn, .gf");
$em = GetSelectionMultiple($selection, "em");


function GetSelectionMultiple($single_element_or_array, $criteria, $delimiter=",")
{
$array_split = explode($delimiter, $criteria);
$remove_emptyones = [];
for($index=0; $index<count($array_split); $index++)
{
    $sel = trim($array_split[$index]);
    if(strlen($sel) > 0)
    {
        $remove_emptyones[] = $sel;
    }
}
$array_split = $remove_emptyones;



//Elements which will be returned
$array_element = [];
$dom_array = [];
if(is_array($single_element_or_array) == false)
{
    $dom_array[] = $single_element_or_array;
}
else
{
    foreach($single_element_or_array as $iterate)
    {
        $dom_array[] = $iterate;
    }
}


for( $domindex=0; $domindex<count($dom_array); $domindex++ )
{
    $current_find = null;
    $dom = $dom_array[$domindex];

    for($index=0; $index<count($array_split); $index++)
    {
        $use = trim($array_split[$index]);
        if(strlen($use) == 0)
            continue;

        if($index == 0)
        {
            $current_find = $dom->find($use);
            foreach($current_find as $element)
            {
                $array_element[] = $element;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Each array element find things now and add them or remove them
            for($check=0; $check<count($array_element); $check++ )
            {
                $parent = $array_element[$check]->parent;
                if($parent == null || $parent == false)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                $current_find = $parent->find($use);
                if($current_find != null && $current_find && count($current_find) > 0)
                {
                    foreach($current_find as $element)
                    {
                        $matches = false;
                        for($c=0; $c<count($array_element); $c++)
                        {
                            if($array_element[$c] === $element)
                            {
                                $matches =true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if($matches == false)
                        {
                            $array_element[$check] = null;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                     $array_element[$check] = null;
                }
            }

            //Remove the null elements
            $newarray = [];
            for($check=0; $check<count($array_element); $check++ )
            {
                $current_find = $array_element[$check];
                if($current_find != null)
                {
                    $newarray[] = $current_find;
                }
            }
            $array_element = $newarray;
        }
    }
 }

    return $array_element;
}
```